# std::map::insert return value?

Tags: c++, graphics

```
typedef TriIndex ...
typedef std::map< TriIndex, unsigned int > VertexMap;
VertexMap vertex_map;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < face.size(); ++i ) { 
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j ) {
        std::pair< VertexMap::iterator, bool > rv = vertex_map.insert( std::make_pair(     face.v[j], vert_idx_counter ) );
        if ( rv.second ) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I took out a snippet from an opengl starter code. I get what it's doing except for the following line:

```
std::pair< VertexMap::iterator, bool > rv = vertex_map.insert( std::make_pair(     face.v[j], vert_idx_counter ) );
```

I get that the line declares a pair called rv with an iterator and a boolean value - .
But on the right hand side, there is vertex_map.insert - but from what i know, insert is a void function. How do you get a pair from inserting a pair to vertex map?

Comment: "from what I know"? Have you seen the manual? : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: "Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place." -- linked documentation

Comment: @ooga wow i've always thought insert was void...well i should've checked the manual first

Comment: oops...i accidentally looked up std::vector::insert instead of std::map::insert.... stupid me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vertex_map is the same as 'std::map< TriIndex, unsigned int >' so you are calling a the insert function of a map, see the docs for more details [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)